# Тем не менее: морфология и синтаксис

Tags: частица-не, синтаксис, тем

Что такое "тем не менее"? Можно ли его назвать наречным выражением и какова его функция в предложении?

Справочник "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации" за 2012 год считает его служебным словом (частицей или союзом). А чем в данном случае частица ТЕМ НЕ МЕНЕЕ отличается от наречия ТЕМ НЕ МЕНЕЕ?

Хотя согласно  этому справочнику  ТЕМ НЕ МЕНЕЕ не имеет вводной функции, всё же в текстах применяется это сочетание в качестве вводного слова, например: "Не касаясь друг друга, они, тем не менее, связаны общим гравитационным полем" (вводное слово). Складывается впечатление, что обособление зависит от позиции сочетания, и при изменении структуры предложения  может измениться и его функция: "Не касаясь друг друга, они связаны тем не менее общим гравитационным полем" (частица).

Так может ли ТЕМ НЕ МЕНЕЕ быть вводным словом и в каких случаях это возможно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Что такое "тем не менее"? Можно ли его
> назвать наречным выражением...

А кто "тем не менее" сейчас так называет? К примеру, авторы справочника "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации" -- В. В. Свинцов, В. М. Пахомов, И. В. Филатова -- в 2010 году действительно употребляли такой термин; см. http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/697/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5 .

Но уже в вышедшем спустя два года бумажном издании -- "частица и союз". После этого была изменена и электронная версия этого справочника: http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_731

> Согласно этому справочнику ТЕМ НЕ
> МЕНЕЕ не имеет вводной функции…

То же и у Розенталя  (см. https://books.google.ru/books?id=VY2LAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA171&dq=%22%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5%22+%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=dIvDVN_tLaHlywOJ0ICgBg&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5%22%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C&f=false ):
***Не являются вводными и не выделяются запятыми слова ведь, вот, будто… тем не менее, вдруг...***

Мне такая категоричность не нравится. Всё-таки это право автора -- как произнести это "тем не менее". А уж от произношения  будет зависеть и пунктуация.

Авторы справочника **"Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и приложений"** О.А. Остроумова и О.Д. Фрамполь о "тем не менее" пишут так:

**ТЕМ НЕ МЕНЕЕ** 1, частица.

1. Редко употребляется в функции вводного для выражения субъективного отношения к какому-либо факту, **только при интонационном подчёркивании:** *Мы, мол, всё понимаем, но**, тем не менее,** должны проявлять вежливость* (В. Шукшин); *Опять же полностью согласен. **Тем не менее,** какие ваши планы?* (С. Довлатов); *Большинство же, пройдя искус поэзии, более к ней никогда не обращалось, кроме как в качестве читателей, сохраняя**, тем не менее,** глубокую признательность за уроки лаконизма и гармонии, у неё полученные* (И. Бродский).
2. Обычно невводное, употребляется в функции частицы (читать без интонационного выделения), не обособляется…

**ТЕМ НЕ МЕНЕЕ** 2, союз.

1. Невводное, употребляется в функции противительного союза (= но), если стоит в абсолютном начале предложения или на стыке простых предложений в составе сложного, не обособляется...
2. Невводное, иногда используется как часть двойного уступительного союза, не обособляется...

Comment: Спасибо, Слава, за ответ. Мне тоже кажется, что вводная функция "тем не менее" всё-таки существует и она связана с его логическим (или интонационным) выделением (а этим  можно управлять, меняя структуру предложения). Но вот остается вопрос: можно ли считать сочетание наречным выражением, почему в справочнике оно называется частицей? Есть ли принципиальная разница между этими функциями?

Comment: "Но вот остается вопрос: можно ли считать сочетание наречным выражением..."=== Ну, назвать-то можно как угодно. Только в предложении это сочетание будет или или частицей, или союзом, или вводным. НО НЕ ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВОМ.

Comment: А почему нет? "Тем не менее" можно заменить выражением "несмотря на это", которое является обстоятельством.

Comment: Что-то в Ваших словах есть... Буду думать!

Comment: Как вариант --  к обороту "несмотря на это" можно поставить обстоятельственный вопрос: несмотря на что? К сочетанию "тем не менее" ни такого, ни иного вопроса, по-моему, не задашь.

Answer (score 2):

Классификация частей речи проистекает из возможных функций в предложении, а у некоторых предметов классификации функций может быть больше одной. "Тем не менее" вполне может быть и вводным словом, например, в случаях противопоставления предшествующему законченному высказыванию (предложению или целому абзацу). Исходное высказывание в виде одного предложения может иметь грамматическую связь с противопоставляемым (с возможностью объединения в одно с ним предложение) или не иметь её (имея только смысловую связь с ним).

Жюль Верн не был путешественником. Тем не менее, в его книгах настолько живо описаны особенности дальних стран, что можно подумать, будто он сам в них побывал.

В примере с перестановкой функция "тем не менее" не меняется, если сохранить запятые. Но если их отбросить, то вносимое противопоставление оказывается направленным на "общим (гравит. полем)", в противоположность подразумеваемым "раздельным". Смысл изменяется с "тем не менее, они *связаны*" на "тем не менее, связаны они *общим* полем". В исходном варианте "тем не менее" может относиться ко всему после деепр. оборота, в изменённом - только к "общности" поля (соответственно, перестаёт быть "вводным словом"). Более наглядна функция "вводного слова" в разбитом на две фразы исходном предложении. Она не изменится при перестановках "тем не менее" на позиции после "оно" или после "связаны" (с запятыми; в обоих случаях появится акцент на "связаны").

Они не касаются друг друга. Тем не менее, они связаны общим гравитационным полем.

Comment: Спасибо, очень внимательно прочитала ваш ответ, но вопросы всё-таки остались. Предположим следующее: словосочетание «тем не менее» в простом предложении может быть (1)  частицей, (2) наречным выражением, (3) вводным словом, например: 
«Не будучи путешественником, он, тем не менее,  очень живо описывал особенности дальних стран» (вводное слово).
«Не будучи путешественником, он очень живо тем не менее описывал особенности дальних стран» (наречие или частица).

Comment: Смысловое значение «тем не менее» в трех функциях практически одинаково. А чем они тогда различаются? Вы отличаете частицу от наречия, от вводного слова? Допустим, частица и наречие связаны с конкретным словом  в предложении, но и вводное выражение может относиться не только ко всему сообщению, но и  к конкретному слову.

Comment: Для  "тем не менее" я различаю два характерных случая.
1. Вводное выражение. Я определяю его именно по признаку отношения к законченному суждению (например, в виде простого предложения с собственными подлежащим и сказуемым). Такое выражение должно быть выделено запятыми. Оно может быть в начале предложения, но и при перестановке может сохранять свою функцию: сместив акцент на единственное сказуемое (или на что-то другое), оно по-прежнему может относиться к высказыванию в целом.

Comment: 2.Всё остальное: если выражение относится к отдельным членам предложения - это нечто другое. В таких случаях может быть противопоставление как однородных членов предложения (двух разных сказуемых, дополнений и т.п.), так и напр. причастного оборота - определению (невзрачный и тем не менее привлекающий внимание некоторых).

В Вашем втором примере я усматриваю всё то же вводное выражение (и оно требует запятых). Потому и смысл тот же, что здесь не отнести "тем не менее" к отдельным частям предложения: есть акцент на "живо", но это слово ничему равнозначному отдельно не противопоставлено.

Comment: Я думаю, что при отсутствии обособления мы логически выделяем слово "живо" (противопоставление: "не был - жИво описывал"). При обособлении центр можно сместить на глагол "описывал" (противопоставление: не был - живо опИсывал. Вводность сочетания заставляет нас делать паузу, вследствие чего акценты смещаются. Поэтому можно считать, что обособление здесь факультативно и важно не само по себе, а для расстановки этих акцентов.

Comment: При отсутствии обособления я интуитивно начинаю искать противопоставляемое слово сразу после "тем не менее", поскольку в случае "невводности" это словосочетание должно находиться "между" двумя противопоставляемыми сущностями. Не найдя там искомого слова или выражения, я заключаю, что "тем не менее" здесь можно отнести только ко всему вместе (при написании нужны запятые, при чтении - паузы).

Comment: В таком качестве "тем не менее" может иметь несколько позиций в предложении, не меняя его смысла. В устной форме по интонации можно догадаться, что говорящий вставляет его "вдогонку", но это не разрушает фразы: сохраняется понимание того, что это относится ко всему суждению, в которое вставлено.

Answer (score 2):

Большое спасибо всем, кто отвечал на вопрос: вы помогли мне составить определенное мнение. Правда, это мнение совершенно субъективное, поэтому не судите его очень строго (только частная точка зрения, ничего большего).

1) Я предполагаю, что следует быть ТОЧНЫМ в терминологии и называть сочетание частицей или наречным выражением (или изменять название) по каким-то ПРИЧИНАМ.

2) Я думаю, что частица ТЕМ НЕ МЕНЕЕ (как и всякая частица) тесно примыкает к слову, которому она придает дополнительное (в данном случае уступительное) значение.

3) Этого нельзя сказать о наречии в роли обстоятельства: связанное с определяемым словом синтаксической связью, оно всё же занимает в предложении достаточно свободную позицию.

4) Сочетанию ТЕМ НЕ МЕНЕЕ такая свобода придает значение вводности. Немного изменив структуру предложения, переставив логическое ударение в нем, мы ослабляем связь сочетания с конкретным словом и относим его ко всему сообщению.

5) Поэтому можно сделать вывод: необособленный вариант - это частица в простом предложении или союз в ССП. Обособленный вариант - это наречное выражение в значении вводного слова

Answer (score 0):

Словарь-справочник по пунктуации 2010 г. утверждает, что *тем не менее* может быть союзом (= но, однако) или наречным выражением (=всё-таки, всё же, несмотря на это):

http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/697/%

Грамота.ру называет выражение частицей в сочетании с противительными союзами «а», «но», а также в предложениях с союзами «хотя», «несмотря на то что», «пусть» и др. и союзом:

http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_731 ТЕМ НЕ МЕНЕЕ, частица и союз

Форум Грамма.ру объясняет, что в последнее время филологи допускают и роль вводного сочетания, как и "однако" в середине предложения, потому что появляется интонация выделения и  значение  субъективной оценки, экспрессии в выражение.

http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.43

Comment: Людмила, скажите, пожалуйста, а вы различаете функцию частицы или наречного выражения (соответственно, обстоятельства) для "тем не менее"? Может быть, нет разницы?

Comment: Людмила: "Словарь-справочник по пунктуации 2010 г... Грамота.ру называет..."===

Людмила, Вы не обратили, наверное, внимание на то, что "Словарь-справочник по пунктуации 2010 г." и словарь на Грамоте.ру -- это ОДИН И ТОТ ЖЕ СЛОВАРЬ. Только на Грамоте.ру -- его более новая  редакция.

Comment: Дорогие товарищи, умерьте свой праведный пыл.Вера, Вы спросили:"Что такое "тем не менее"? Можно ли его назвать наречным выражением и какова его функция в предложении?" Я ответила, что можно, так и называют, и привела пример (кстати,и сейчас ещё называют, вот в 2013 г.-http://aprikablog.com/2013/10/tem-ne-menee/) Однако речь здесь не о части речи как таковой,а о строении выражения:в его состав входит наречие "менее". В словарях не всегда указывается, какой частью речи является всё выражение.Позже стали указывать, что всё выражение может играть роль частицы.

Comment: О союзе споров не было, а вот к частицам часто не относили целые выражения, такие как всё-таки , всё же, всё равно, в том числе и тем не менее.Их называли "выражениями". Роль в предложении, конечно,служебная - союз или частица, а теперь вот стали признавать и роль вводного слова, потому что выделить паузой хочется, что и делают многие, таких примеров в Нацкорпусе много, а раз появилось в речи, частотно употребление - закрепится и в языке, в словарях.